# Record inserted in child when update the parent

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

With the code below when I update the object `Employee` a new record is added in the `Language` table and I don't understand why. The `LanguageId` has a value and I set the `Language` (see info in the code). The `Employee` record is updated with as `LanguageId` the newly created.

What I do wrong ?

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public virtual int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Language); 
}

private void Update(Employee employee)
{
    //LanguageId in employee object has a value, OK
    //Language is null
    employee.Login = employee.Login.ToUpper();
    employee.Language = myRepository.Get(employee.LanguageId);

    myRepository.Update(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some tips that I want to share with you. If you want to configure a one to one relationship using a FK, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent end also be the foreign key, but I think this is not your case because, one `Language` can be associated to more than one `Employee`, so you need to configure a one-to-many relationship. The configuration of your relationship would be like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasRequired(t => t.Language).
                                   WithMany().HasForeignKey(e=> e.LanguageId);
}
```

If you want update the `Language` in a `Employee`, you have two options:

- Setting the FK property `LanguageId`
- Setting the navigation property`Language`.

If you already set the `LanguageId` with the Id of a `Language` that already exist in DB, you don't need to find that `Language` and set the `Language` property in your `Employee` instance. Setting the FK property is enough to EF to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong code.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}
public class Language
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

If emplyee.LanguageId has value then EF bind Language object autamatically.

If you want to save Employee without language property then you have to make it optional in OnModelCreating and in Employee class:

```
public int? LanguageId {get; set;}
```